# How to use $.get "Additional Data" in PHP-side

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
$.get ("php/checkuser.php", {username : "stackexchange"}, function(data){
    console.log(data)
});
```

How do I retrieve/handle the "username" in the PHP file? as far as I can tell it isn't stored in a variable and there is no further documentation on the relevant jQuery website.

I am clearly lacking some simple knowledge here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery get() method is used to send a HTTP GET request.

So when this method executes, the URL fired is of the below form

`http://example.com/checkuser.php?username=stackexchange`

Here "username" is what we would call a query parameter. To get the value of a GET query parameter in PHP, you would need to use the [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) superglobal, which is an associative array.

So, to access the value of the username GET param, you would need to do something like the below

```
$username = $_GET["username"];
```

That's pretty much it. :-)

Comment: This was the correct answer to my question but my issue was with another function which I have since fixed. Thanks for the help :)